# How can I store the value of a subquery into a variable in Hana Studio?

Tags: subquery, hana, sql-scripts

I would like to know how can I store the value of subquery to use it in an operation after it recieve the value. For example:

```
Select IDTruck
, TruckPrice = (select "TruckPrice" from "Table1"  where  ("TruckID" = '123'))

, TruckUnit = (select "TruckUnit" from "Table2" )

, TruckPrice * TruckUnit as "PriceTotal"
from Table3
```

I just want to store the value and then use it in the operation so I don't have to do the select again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why it should be necessary to store the values in variables for usage in your case. I think the calculation can be done also by joining just the data (assuming that table3 contains a reference to table1 and table2).

Your example above would also not work, because TruckPrice and TruckUnits are no atomar results.

So please try to refactor your statement to use joins.

Comment: Hi Florian, I'm sorry it was my mistake because I didn't specify what is the behaviour of the subquery but I found the solution with the clause "with". My aim was to avoid redundancy of the subqueries. Again sorry for not being specific.